# Load testing an application that uses Azure sso authorization code flow with jmeter

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, jmeter, single-sign-on, jmeter-plugins

I am new to Jmeter. I want to load test an application that is protected with Azure sso authorization code. Is there any reference documentation that I could read to achieve this?

I have tried this: https://www.aurigait.com/blog/performance-testing-on-auth2-apis-using-jmeter-and-server-cmd-line/ but it doesn’t work

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that using a browser is a good idea, given you properly [configure JMeter to behave like a real browser](https://How%20to%20make%20JMeter%20behave%20more%20like%20a%20real%20browser) you should be able to replicate browser's network footpring with 100% accurracy using JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler.

Bypassing OAuth authorization flow in JMeter it's a matter of [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start).

You can check out [atlassian-microsoft-oauth.jmx](https://github.com/aboyfromipanema/jmeter-oauth/blob/main/atlassian-microsoft-oauth.jmx) example script, it might not fully work for your environment but the idea should be the same.